# Accessing one crate through another in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to port in `serde_json` through cucumber. `gherkin_rust` v0.10.1 lists it under "[build-dependencies]". How do I access it without adding it to the toml file / using an extern crate call?

```
 └── cucumber v0.10.2
    ├── gherkin_rust v0.10.1
    │   ├── peg v0.6.3
    │   │   ├── peg-macros v0.6.3 (proc-macro)
    │   │   │   ├── peg-runtime v0.6.3
    │   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.32 (*)
    │   │   │   └── quote v1.0.10 (*)
    │   │   └── peg-runtime v0.6.3
    │   ├── textwrap v0.12.1
    │   │   └── unicode-width v0.1.9
    │   ├── thiserror v1.0.30
    │   │   └── thiserror-impl v1.0.30 (proc-macro)
    │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.32 (*)
    │   │       ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
    │   │       └── syn v1.0.81 (*)
    │   └── typed-builder v0.7.1 (proc-macro)
    │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.32 (*)
    │       ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
    │       └── syn v1.0.81 (*)
    │   [build-dependencies]
    │   ├── heck v0.3.3
    │   │   └── unicode-segmentation v1.8.0
    │   ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
    │   ├── serde v1.0.130
    │   │   └── serde_derive v1.0.130 (proc-macro)
    │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.32 (*)
    │   │       ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
    │   │       └── syn v1.0.81 (*)
    │   ├── serde_json v1.0.68
    │   │   ├── itoa v0.4.8
    │   │   ├── ryu v1.0.5
    │   │   └── serde v1.0.130 (*)
    │   └── syn v1.0.81 (*)
```

Comment: You don't. If it wasn't a _build_ dependency, and if `gherkin_rust` re-exported it (e.g. through `pub use`), then you could access it through `gherkin_rust`, but here you will need to add it to your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: @Jmb Post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can not** access to it through another crate unless that other crate **reexports** it publicly (ex `pub use::cool_crate`).

Just add whatever you need to your `Cargo.toml`. Notice that dependencies are not used more than once, so there should not be any difference but the usage through namespacing.